No Magic Number when trying to unlock Linksys PAP2 Ver.2
I just purchased a Linksys PAP2 Ver.2 from ebay. When I was trying to set it up I realized it was locked to chartermi.net a Spectrum.net company.
I already tried to contact them and they said it was rental equipment and would not help me. It is on Firmware Version 1.00.22, I have figured out the logins of the admin and user accounts but not the master Admin account. I have tried all of the unlocking guides and they all end in a No/Magic Number Config Error. I have no access to /Upgrade but do have access to /update.html but can not transfer any files via tftp. Anybody have any other ideas on how to help?
NOTE: also since it was reset from original config, I can no longer access the IVR
